# import a csv from google cloud storage to google cloud automatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I  want to import a csv file from google cloud storage to google cloud sql and for this i am using the following query . when i execute the query in apps script i am getting following errors
*getservice() is not defined
arguments ----Arguments (219473067)
service---- undefined
token----undefined
result-----undefined
i-----undefined
f----undefined
path-----undefined
payload-----undefined

and the java script i used is

```
function uploadtoCloudSQL() {

var service = getService();

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log(service.getAuthorizationUrl());
    return;
  }

  var token = service.getAccessToken();

  // Getting list of files to be processed

var result = JSON.parse(
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/test/o', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    }).getContentText());

 for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
    if (result.items[i].name.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
      files.push(result.items[i].name);
    }
  }

  for (var f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {

    var path = files[f].split("/");

    var payload =
      '{"importContext" : { "csvImportOptions": {"table":"test_table"}, "fileType": "CSV", "database": "nmp", "uri": "gs://revealer_test/data/Sample_data.csv"}}'
      .replace("data", path[0])
      .replace("Sample_data.csv", path[1]);

    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/PROJECT/instances/INSTANCE/import', {
      method: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      },
      payload: payload,
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/test/o/' + encodeURIComponent(files[f]), {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });

    // Wait for the previous import job to end
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

  }

}
```

please help me to rectify the error..
Thank you

Comment: As stated in this [link](http://initcode.info/why_do_i_get_ldquo_service_is_not_definedrdquo_error_message_in_angular_page), you're getting an error `getservice() is not defined` because you never injected your service into controller or maybe you have not added service script in `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrt Cloud SQL part, are you using the right project name and instance name in the googleapis url?

I see https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/PROJECT/instances/INSTANCE/import. You should replace PROJECT and INSTANCE with your own values.